GKE set custom response code for ingress healthcheck
I'm trying to create a simple ingress for kibana with something like this
## kibana-ingress.yml ##
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kibana-ingress
  namespace: monit
spec:
  rules:
    - host: 34.72.13.154
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: kibana-kibana
                port:
                  number: 5601

It seems that kibana has a health check at /app/kibana but when Auth is enabled this path will be redirected to 302 and thus causing the GKE ingress healthcheck to fail (as it expects a response code to be 200).
In the doc, I saw the mention of Expected Response so I tried the following backend config
## healthcheck-backendconfig.yml ##
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: healthcheck-backendconfig
  namespace: monit
spec:
  logging:
    enable: true
    sampleRate: 0.1
  healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: 600
    timeoutSec: 40
    healthyThreshold: 1
    unhealthyThreshold: 3
    type: HTTP
    requestPath: /app/kibana
    port: 5601
    expectedResponse: 302

But this fails
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "healthcheck-backendconfig.yml": BackendConfig in version "v1" cannot be handled as a BackendConfig: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.healthCheck.expectedResponse"

Is there a way to use a custom response code in this case? anything than 5xx should work here

The error message you are getting is due to the expectedResponse field not existing. You can read more about the available fields for a BackendConfig health check in the following docs.
GKE official documentation states you can't change the expected response from HTTP 200 (OK).

from the doc it seems the expected response from HTTP 200 (OK) cannot be changed if the values for the health endpoint were inferred but I'm providing them manually here!
